# What are snap docker and deb docker.io?

Tags: ubuntu

In a Ubuntu 20.04.1 machine, I installed Docker (following the official documentation at docs.docker.com) and everything works fine.

```
r$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
```

But when I mistyped the `docker` command, I got a surprise:

```
r$ doocker

Command 'doocker' not found, did you mean:

  command 'docker' from snap docker (19.03.11)
  command 'docker' from deb docker.io (19.03.8-0ubuntu1.20.04)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

What are `snap docker` and `deb docker.io`? And why do they refer to different versions?
Do they can interfere with the correct functioning of "my" version? Can I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu comes with 2 distinct software packaging systems, deb and snap.

> Snap is a software packaging and deployment system developed by Canonical for the operating systems that use the Linux kernel. [...] Snaps are self-contained applications running in a sandbox with mediated access to the host system. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager))

That info you got just indicates that docker is available from these two sources. Not necessary that one of those is currently installed, so no need to remove anything.